# Why is this not reading the accelerometer with Core Motion?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, accelerometer

I tried setting up a simple program to read the accelerometer of an iPad, but for some reason the following code in my view controller isn't doing anything. As you can see, the handler closure is supposed to call the method "*outputAccelerationData*", but when I set a breakpoint in that method it appears that it isn't being called at all despite the fact that the accelerometer update interval is set to 0.1 seconds. Any idea why this code doesn't work?

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    let manager=CMMotionManager()
    var accelerationX: Double=0.0
    var accelerationY: Double=0.0
    var accelerationZ: Double=0.0
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabelX: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabelY: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabelZ: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if manager.isAccelerometerAvailable
        {
            manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval=0.1
            let queue=OperationQueue.main
            manager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: queue, withHandler: { [weak self] (data, error) in
                if let acceleration=data?.acceleration
                {
                    self?.outputAccelerationData(data: acceleration)
                }

            })
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error: Accelerometer not available on this device")
        }
    }

    func outputAccelerationData(data:CMAcceleration)
    {
        self.accelerationX=data.x
        self.accelerationY=data.y
        self.accelerationZ=data.z
        valueLabelX.text=String(format: "%.2f", self.accelerationX)
        valueLabelY.text=String(format: "%.2f", self.accelerationY)
        valueLabelZ.text=String(format: "%.2f", self.accelerationZ)
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that you're not checking for errors in your code. Have you checked to see if you are getting an error? If so, "data" could potentially be nil and self?.outputAccelerationData(data: acceleration) would not be called.

Comment: Just FYI, docs say: "Because the processed events might arrive at a high rate, using the main operation queue is not recommended"

Comment: @matt - Yes, I know. But all three examples I could find on the internet of the use of Core Motion to read the accelerometer showed them using "OperationQueue.main" for this purpose. I may try to use some other queue in the future, but it appears that in practice a lot of people simply use the main operation queue.

Comment: @Jake - After I edited my code to see if I could read out the state of the error variable and running the code, I noticed that it now stopped on the breakpoint that I put in "outputAccelerationData" (!). For some reason it suddenly started calling that method. I couldn't see how the additional error-checking code that I quickly put in could have possibly been responsible for that, so I quickly deleted that additional code and the program I listed above now works! Satisfying but also a bit disconcerting because I have no idea why the code now works or if it will stop working. Weird.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I suspect that the accelerometer hardware was just warming up so that you didn't get readings at first. As Jake said, you have no error-checking (you are not testing the value of `error` or testing to see whether `data` is nil) so your `if let` was failing and you had no check on it. Then it succeeded when the hardware was ready.

Comment: Voting to close, as no problem can now be reproduced.

Comment: @SamuelWeir - It happens to us all my friend...

Comment: @Jake, Matt - Thanks guys. Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Final note: The problem of the accelerometer not working in Core Motion reappeared with the same symptoms. I cleaned the build folder then quit and restarted Xcode and now the accelerometer works again. It appears to be an Xcode bug.